# Delete From a Database Using Session ($_SESSION)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a record i want to remove from the database. I have so far been able save to the mysql database now i have several information in several rows, now suppose the information isnt the needed one, i want to delete it from the database. Thats what i am trying to achieve here

I tried this

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('inc/config.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('Location: signon.php');
}
?>

<?php
require_once('inc/config.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die ('Cannot connect: '.mysqli_error());
$sql = "SELECT * FROM education_info WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$id = $row['id'];
$username = $row['username'];

$sql2 = "DELETE FROM education_info WHERE id = $id" ;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
mysqli_close($con);

header("Refresh:0; url=EDWE.php");
?>
```

Only that the information still remains present in the database, How do i go about deleting it completely, if not needed?

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Check for errors after execute SQL Statements

Comment: @Jens yes, just first of checking on Localhost, after then i use prepared statements before i deploy to main server :)

Comment: Why testing something what you not want to Use?

Comment: @Jens, I do want to use it. office project, tho it would be on LAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing wrong variable while executing delete query:

```
$sql2 = "DELETE FROM education_info WHERE id = $id" ;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql2); //<---pass $sql2
```

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Comment: O Great! i didnt even look there Thanks a Whole lot for your help.